# How to call Visual Force page in a page layout

Tags: apex, community

I need to call a visualForcePage in pageLayoute and display some information.
 there is my code:
But I receive a message error   : 
Content cannot be displayed: The link you followed isn?t valid. This page requires a CSRF confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce administrator.

Please I need your help.

[image]

Page :

```
    <!-- CSS STYLE TO NOT USE WORD WRAP -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .pbTitle {
        white-space: nowrap
        }   

    </style> 

    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Voucher In Project :" id="mainBlock" >        
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Voucher Information" id="resultsBlock" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!VoucherInProject_List}" var="o" >
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!o.Name}"></apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>                  
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>  
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class Olympus_Project_controller {

    Olympus_Project_Model OPM;
    public String   linkServerPage {get;set;}

    public list<Olympus_Voucher__c> VoucherInProject_List {get ;set;}
    public Olympus_Project_controller(ApexPages.StandardController acon)
    {  
        linkServerPage=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ;
    }

    public void getVoucherInProject()
    {
        OPM = new Olympus_Project_Model(linkServerPage);
        VoucherInProject_List = OPM.Ovc_L;
        system.debug('Olympus_Project_controller.VoucherInProject_List => '+ VoucherInProject_List);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have "Require CSRF protection on GET requests" checked on the details page of your visualforce page?